# Combine and minify templates with CoffeeScript / Cake

Tags: coffeescript, minify

I have a `src/templates/` directory full of mustache templates. How would I combine and minify the contents of those, so they're available for use in my CoffeeScript app?

I'm already following the directions at https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/%5BHowTo%5D-Compiling-and-Setting-Up-Build-Tools for combining and minifying my CoffeeScript src into js.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, I'll assume that your templates are being exported to the global object (e.g. each one does `window.userpane =` rather than just `userpane =`). That's the most important thing. If you're doing that, and you're concatenating and compiling successfully, then the only thing left is to have automatic minification after each concatenation.

Short answer: **There's no good tool for this yet.** Your best option is to extend your existing Cakefile with a line like

```
fs.watchFile 'concatenated.js', ->
  exec 'uglifyjs concatenated.js'
```

(To install [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS), run `npm install uglify-js`.)

Now, this won't solve the problem of ensuring that your scripts are concatenated in a sensible order. (For instance, if you have `window.templates = {}` in file A and `templates.userpane =` in file B, then it's very important that file A be concatenated before file B.) For that, you should keep an eye on [Sprockets](http://getsprockets.org/installation_and_usage), which lets you indicate at the top of each JS file what its dependencies are, then combine them in an order that respects those dependencies. The creator of Sprockets, Sam Stephenson, is an active member of the CoffeeScript community, and first-class support for CoffeeScript in Sprockets is coming in Sprockets 2 (repo [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets)).

**Update:** Here's a Cake task to do the actual reading and concatenating of everything in the `template` directory:

```
templateJs = ''
files = fs.readdirSync 'template'
for file in files
  contents = fs.readFileSync file, 'utf8'
  name = file.replace /\..*/, '' # remove extension
  templateJs += "window.#{name} = '#{contents}';"
```

Then prepend your concatenated JS with `templateJs`. Note that this assumes that there are no single quotes (`'`) in the template. Either put backslashes in front of them or consistently use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try and see how it goes.

Comment: So one thing your answer doesn't address is actually getting the contents of my templates into a JS object (e.g. `window.templates`). The template files are just pure mustache, so I need a Cake task that reads in those templates, puts them on a global object and inserts at the beginning of my concatenated file.

Comment: (the other one) I've updated my answer with a Cake task that should take care of most of that. All that's left is to similarly read in and compile your `.coffee` files, then concatenate the resulting JS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for the slow response - SO's lack of reply notifications drives me crazy.