# CoffeeScript build setup that supports unit testing?

Tags: coffeescript, build-process, qunit

I want to use CoffeeScript for building what will essentially be a JavaScript library.

I would just like to be able to

1. define some classes, with inheritance
2. keep my code in several files
3. write some unit tests (QUnit or whatever works, preferably writing tests in CoffeeScript)
4. (ideally) have the project watched and built automatically while I work

This seems reasonable, no? My plan is just having the unit tests run against the compiled JavaScript, in a browser, although if I can run them straight in node.js that's even better.

Currently I'm trying to do this with [CoffeeToaster](https://github.com/serpentem/coffee-toaster) and [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/), using two different CoffeeToaster configurations, one with tests and one without. It is working, but perhaps somebody has a better suggestion? Should I ditch CoffeeToaster and do it with [Cake](http://coffeescript.org/#cake)? Or get another unit testing framework? Can anybody point me to a tutorial for this? I'm making a clientside JS lib, so I don't want to involve Rails etc.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the capitalization, @PPvG, I was lazy. FWIW my dual CoffeScript configuration plan is working now, but I'm still curious whether anybody else has other (better) suggestions.

Comment: Glad to hear your setup is working, although you're still asking for a "better suggestion". Can you elaborate? What are you still missing?

Comment: I was hoping to manage the correct order of concatenating files. Related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758715/combine-and-minify-templates-with-coffeescript-cake - that's why I was looking at CoffeeToaster. But maybe I'll just use a manual order in a cakefile.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using:

- **[Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)** as the test runner and **[should.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js)** for assertions;
- [Mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) to intercept certain `require` calls for isolated testing with mocks/stubs of required libraries;
- *[JSCoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage) for instrumenting the code for code coverage reports.

My code lives in `src/` and I write my tests in CoffeeScript. I use `make` to build and test the code.

- `make build` compiles the CoffeeScript in `src/` to JavaScript in `lib/`.
- `make test` builds the code and then runs the tests in `test/`.
- `make monitor` watches and runs the tests as soon as they change. Unfortunately it *doesn't* recompile the code. I use a Vim keybinding to call `make`, which also triggers Mocha to re-run the tests.
  **Edit:** If this bothers you, you could run [`coffee --watch`](http://coffeescript.org/#usage) `-o lib/ -c src/`.
- `make coverage` generates a code coverage report and puts it in `lib-cov/report.html`.

My `Makefile` looks somewhat like this:

```
COFFEE = ./node_modules/.bin/coffee --compile
MOCHA = NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha
MOCHA_OPTS = \
    --compilers coffee:coffee-script \
    --require should \
    --colors
REPORTER = spec

build:
    @$(COFFEE) --output lib/ src/

test: build
    @$(MOCHA) --reporter $(REPORTER) $(MOCHA_OPTS)

monitor:
    @$(MOCHA) --reporter min $(MOCHA_OPTS) \
    --watch --growl

coverage: instrument
    @MYLIB_COV=1 $(MOCHA) $(MOCHA_OPTS) \
    --reporter html-cov > lib-cov/report.html

instrument: build
    @rm -rf ./lib-cov
    @jscoverage ./lib ./lib-cov

.PHONY: build test monitor coverage instrument
```

You could probably use the above with very little modification.

To generate the coverage report with `make coverage`, the tests must be run against the instrumented code in `lib-cov/` instead of the code in `lib/`. To make this possible, three things are needed:

1. The `Makefile` should set an environment variable, like `MYLIB_COV` *(change the name as you like).*
2. Your `index.js` should look at this environment variable and `require` either `lib/` or `lib-cov/` accordingly:

   ```
   // index.js
   module.exports = process.env.MYLIB_COV
     ? require('./lib-cov/mylib')
     : require('./lib/mylib');
   ```

   *If you need exports from multiple source files, you can combine them here. If you have something other than `index.js` as 'main' in your package.json, don't forget to change it.*
3. Your tests should `require '../'`:

   ```
   # test/test.user.coffee
   describe 'User', ->
     User = {}

     before ->
       {User} = require '../'

     describe '#equals()', ->
       describe 'when users have the same username and host', ->
         it 'should return true', ->
           user1 = new User 'user', 'some.host.foo'
           user2 = new User 'user', 'some.host.foo'
           user1.equals(user2).should.be.true

     # etc.
   ```

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to find out whether they need Mockery and how to use it if they do. I will point out, though, that the `require` call in the test snippet above is done inside `before` for a reason.

Happy coding!